# Download all Stack Overflow podcasts onto my iPhone

Tags: iphone, podcasts

I want to copy all of the [Stack Overflow podcasts](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/?W4) onto my iPhone. Unfortunately, iTunes will only let me get the last 10. Nik suggested a method of importing MP3s into iTunes, but it appears that this would make them appear in the music section rather than the podcast section. Is there any way to easily do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have downloaded and imported all the MP3 files using nik's method:

1. Make sure you're using iTunes 9.
2. In the Music list, select all files you want to mark as being a podcast.
3. Right-click, and select **Get Info**.
4. Go to the **Options** tab, set the **Media Kind** option to be 'Podcast' and click the **OK** button.

Answer (score 3):

[How to copy mp3 files onto iPhone](http://www.zimbio.com/member/itnewswire/articles/3555994/How+copy+mp3+files+iPhone)

> You have downloaded lots of mp3 files from Internet, now you are wondering how to copy them onto your iPhone and play them.
>
> 1. Open iTunes on your computer. Click Library->Music from the left panel.
> 2. Use Windows Explorer or from My computer to locate your mp3 files on Windows.
> 3. Select the mp3 files, drag them into the Music window.
> 4. Connect your iPhone with your computer with the iPhone cable.
>      Your iPhone should be shown in the Device section on the left panel.
> 5. Click the Music tab, check "Sync music", and "All songs and play lists".
>      Click the "Sync" button.
>
> You can also drag your mp3 file directly to the iPhone icon in the device section.
>   iTunes will keep another copy of your mp3 files. So, make sure you have enough disk space.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. Is there anyway I can get these mp3s to appear as podcasts?